# Ho to bind to slice values in go (gin) form?

Tags: go, mgo, go-gin

Using go and gin-gonic, I'd like to post a simple form containing two tag fields and then save it to mongodb.

Here is the form:

```
      <form action="/quotes/{{ .quote.Id.Hex }}" method="POST">    
          <input type="text" name="author" value="{{ .quote.Author }}">     
          <textarea name="body" rows="3">{{ .quote.Body }}</textarea>       

          <input name="tag" value="" >    
          <input name="tag" value="" >      

         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

And the handler is:

```
func Create(c *gin.Context) {
    db := c.MustGet("db").(*mgo.Database)
    quote := models.Quote{}
    err := c.Bind(&quote)
    if err != nil {
        c.Error(err)
        return
    }

    //To debug
    fmt.Println("form post values\n")
    for t, v := range c.Request.Form["tag"] {
      fmt.Println(t, v) 
    }

    //To debug
    fmt.Println(quote)

    err = db.C(models.CollectionQuote).Insert(quote)
    if err != nil {
        c.Error(err)
    }
    c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/quotes")
}
```

Now the problem is as for `form post values` I get:

```
0 mytag1
1 mytag2
```

and  `quote details` yields something like:

```
{ObjectIdHex("") some-author somebody [] }
```

The quote model is like this:

```
// Quote model
type Quote struct {
    Id        bson.ObjectId `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Author     string        `json:"author" form:"author" binding:"required" bson:"author"`
    Body      string        `json:"body" form:"body" binding:"required" bson:"body"`
    Tag       []string      `json:"tag" bson:"tag"`

}
```

So the tag values are received but not binded. 
I'm wondeirng how can I fix this and get the tags from the form? 
I've looked at the gin [guid](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) but could not find anything about this sort of forms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the model struct. 
I forgot to add `form:"tag"` to the model. So the tag did not bind.